# Slang word for social network/app fame

Tags: single-word-requests, social-media

There was a word popularized by a social media app that was famous a few years ago that purports to rank people by their social network reach, the amount of followers or likes people have. I remember it being the name of the app but I can't remember it now.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: @marcellothearcane how so? It's definitely an english word...

Comment: Could you add the research you have done? Even a list of apps that aren't it.

Comment: @marcellothearcane I don't understand what kind of research I'm expected to do, so bizarre.

Comment: no matter, you've answered it yourself since my comment. It's not a particularly english question in my opinion, but the research could have been scrolling through the app/play store and told us what names weren't it.

Comment: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5043/194281

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Suddenly remembered now, the word was clout, the app spelled it with a k.

Comment: @Cascabel This is an answer to the question. It's very short, and not a good answer at all without at least a dictionary definition, including attribution and quotation, but it's still an answer—and appropriate *as* an answer in that sense. (People are allowed to answer their own questions.)